# JQuery Anmiations Laggy IE9 Fullscreen

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-ui, internet-explorer

My question is of miscelanious nature.

I'm using JQuery with a few animations.
I like the animations and they're working pretty good in the common browsers.

But I've got one strange behavior.
On an older Computer in the Network the animations(toggleslide) and all ui controls(datepicker etc.) er very laggy WHEN IE is used and JUST when IE is maximized.

Does anybody know where I can start analyzing ?
I can post code etc. if necessary, but I don't think it's the code, because also on the old machine it works pretty good IF IE isn't maximized.
I can resize IE till it almost is maximized and it still works correct, but when it's total maximized its' laggy....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is related with the IE9 Setting "Softwarerendering". 
When this is disabled, and an Computer with an onboard graphiccard from 1800 is used, it lags because the GPU is not good enough.

So when you enable the software rendering it works quiet better. Not perfect, but better.

In IE8 etc. this problem doesn't happen because they don't use GPU rendering on an old computer like that. And the other browsers like FF or Chrome have a strong JS-Enigne so it works with software rendering perfectly.

Solved.